# Yii2 на хостинге ставит ссылки на тестовый сайт

Tags: yii2, хостинг

Перенёс все файлы проекта на хостинг, а движок каким-то макаром получает адрес тестового сайта, ноторый у меня ссылается на локальный комп, и пытается грузить с него. Вот [гляньте](http://joxi.ru/1A5zZQ7SK4qeZr):
В файле AppAsserts.php переменную public `$baseUrl` я вместо '@web' задал адрес своего сайта, и файлы которые я в контроллере коннекчу подключились. А вот что делать с файлами которые в конфиге подключаются? Каким таким макаром он сохранил адрес старого сайта? Как сделать, чтоб файлы грузились с нового сайта?

Код AppAssets.php

```
namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '';
    public $baseUrl = 'http://здесь новый адрес моего сайта.esy.es';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    //'/js/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

конфиг `/frontend/config/main.php`:

```
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'modules' => [
        'api' => [
            'class' => 'frontend\modules\api\Api',
        ]
    ],
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],

        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [  
                'defaultRoute' => 'site/index',
                //['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'api/items/<id:\d+>' => 'api/items', 'verb' => 'GET'],
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['api/items', 'api/items/<id:\d+>','api/categories']],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

файл `/common/config/main.php`

```
return [
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],

    'request' => [
            'baseUrl' => ''
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [  
                'defaultRoute' => 'site/index',
                //['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'api/items/<id:\d+>' => 'api/items', 'verb' => 'GET'],
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['api/items', 'api/items/<id:\d+>','api/categories']],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: Скажите, если нужно какую-то инфу предоставить, я покопаюсь в коде.

Comment: Выкладывайте код вашего `AppAssets` и конфига.......и зачем вы вообще трогали `@web`? Это же алиас который привязан к папке проекта

Comment: Вот AppAssets http://pastebin.com/XCYVKBW0
А вот http://pastebin.com/7X2MGxS8 конфиг /frontend/config/main.php

Comment: А вот http://pastebin.com/RzPrzdLP файл /common/config/main.php

Comment: Для начала вам надо вернуть назад $basePath и $baseUrl. Чтобы они выглядели вот так: public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';

Comment: Теперь все ресурсы грузятся со старого адреса. NetBeans-ом данная строка "local.test.ru" не ищется.

Answer (score 1):

Короче, проблема совершенно дурацкая. В стандартном layout движка, который он создал есть в html коде такой тег:

```
<base href="http://local.test.ru/" />
```

По хорошему эту ботву нужно было сразу вынести в конфиг, а тут тянуть как параметр конфига, что-то вроде

```
Yii::$app->params['mySiteAdress']
```

Но я этого сразу не сделал, а сейчас вот по граблям шагаю.

Comment: Решение дурацкое . Используйте Yii::app()->baseUrl